# Can a men wear girl dhoti style pajama?

Tags: men

I am a male person.
I sometimes wear dhoti pajama instead of pant. I wear male shirts and i looks like a male but i like to wear the only one thing that belongs to a girl and this is dhoti pajama. but I don't look like a girl. or I m not a rainbow. I just want to wear this pajama for feeling comfort while sleeping and at my home also. Is it haram for me to wearing a dhoti pajama?

I have given a photo below of dhoti pajama...

[image: dhoti pajama pic]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes , if it is long enough that covers from the naval to the knee. [1]

"Allah's Messenger (ﷺ) cursed those men who are in the similitude (assume the manners) of women and those women who are in the similitude (assume the manners) of men.-Sahih al-Bukhari 5885"

So, if you have a unisex clothing then it doesn't imply imitating women. Only if you wear clothing that is exclusive for women only then it is not allowed as per the above Hadith.

Also, dhoti is considered to be worn by men too to my knowledge so it shouldn't be a problem in sha Allah. But if your dhoti is a variant that is exclusive for women then it is advisable to avoid it.
Allah knows best.

[1] https://islamqa.info/en/34976